# Avalondock how to set tab width of LayoutDocument

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalondock

The tabs that show up for LayoutDocument have short titles, like AA,AB,AC. Consequently, their tab sizes are relatively small.

Is there a way to manually set a fixed width for the tabs?

```
    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" AllowMixedOrientation="True">
        <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
            <themes:AeroTheme/>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>

        <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>                    
            <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane >
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="AA" CanClose="False" >
                            <my:LGDCSimulator/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="AB" CanClose="False">
                            <my:OtherCompanyDCSimulator/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
            </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set width globally for all `LayoutDocument` in `DockingManager` resources:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" AllowMixedOrientation="True">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />                   
        </Style>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.Resources>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <avalonDock:AeroTheme/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
    ...
```